# Does postfix depend on exim?

Tags: postfix, exim

I wanted to uninstall exim4 as I am using postfix now on Debian 9. However, when I stopped exim4 using "sudo service exim4 stop", postfix also stopped. Does postfix depend on exim, or can I completely remove exim?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no dependencies between postfix and exim4 but you can check dependecies on your own with `apt-cache depends postfix` or `apt-cache depends exim4`.